# mysqldump.exe is creating blank mysql database backup file when mysqldump exe is invoked through java

Tags: java

Following is my code.I don't know why it is not working.After debugging it,I found
    that runtimeProcess return "java.lang.ProcessImpl@1afe17b" and processComplete returns
    1.I think i am not able to construct command which i am passing to .exec.Please helpme.

```
public static boolean backupDB(String Database, String Dbuser, String Password) throws    IOException, InterruptedException 
{
Process runtimeProcess;
try{
runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C","C:\\Program     Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -u"+Dbuser+" -p"+Password+Database+"       >F:\\backup.sql"});
System.out.println(runtimeProcess);
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
System.out.println(processComplete);
if (processComplete == 0) {
System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
return true;
}
else{
System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
}
}catch (Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}
return false;
```

Comment: why you are using runtime preffered to use ProcessBuilder

Comment: ok, will try with ProcessBuilder also. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be an artefact of the way that you wrote the Question, but this doesn't look correct:

```
  "C:\\Program     Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqldump.exe"
```

You've got 5 spaces between `Program` and `Files`, where there is normally only 1.  That could be enough to prevent the shell from finding the executable.

---

**UPDATE**

I think you need to find out what is being written to stderr.  The simple way would be to redirect that to a different file.  (I'm not sure what syntax you use to do that in Windows command language ...)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. But actually code is runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C","C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -u"+Dbuser+" -p"+Password+Database+"  >F:\\backup.sql"});                                           In my post it is getting displayed with more spaces

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe -uroot -proot1 mysql > F:\backup.sql
java.lang.ProcessImpl@16fd0b7
1
Could not create the backup  //this is my console output

Comment: complete console output with debug prospective

mysql
root
root1
F:\backup.sql
 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe -uroot -proot1 mysql > F:\backup.sql
java.lang.ProcessImpl@60e277
732
java.io.FileInputStream@1e07d3e
null
false
java.lang.Object@166fdde
java.io.FileDescriptor@a53502
-1
720
1
1
java.io.BufferedOutputStream@13e86ec
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
java.io.FileOutputStream@dea6bc
java.io.BufferedInputStream@c199f
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
java.io.FileInputStream@194a1e9
0
-1
0
1 @Stephen C

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward method would be to first try out the command on command line
and use a String as a parameter  rather than a String[] array.

```
String cmd = "C:\\Program     Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -u"+Dbuser+" -p"+Password+Database+"       >F:\\backup.sql"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Failing that, you can always use the following to figure out what is going on
behind the scenes.

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
r.traceInstructions(true);
r.traceMethodCalls(true);
r.exec("your command")
```

Comment: Hi Milind, Thanks for suggestion.If i do not use exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C",executeCmd}); Then java gives error saying that unable to find mysqlsump.exe...@Milind

Comment: String executeCmd = "mysqldump.exe -u"+Dbuser+" -p"+Password+space+Database+ " > "+path;
//runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/C","Start",executeCmd});
  //runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C executeCmd");
  //runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C Start executeCmd");

Comment: Following worked (i did not add path of bin of mysql to path variable)

Comment: runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/C",executeCmd}); //here String executeCmd="mysqldump.exe -u"+Dbuser+" -p"+Password+space+Database+ " > "+path;  Thanks for help @Milind,@Stephen C

Comment: Entry of path of mysql (bin folder) to user environment variable is mandatory